# Increase decimal places in matplotlib pandas python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe that has 6 decimal places that I would like to plot using matplotlib:

```
980  1.088760
981  1.088770
982  1.088770
983  1.088740
984  1.088740
```

[image]

How can I increase it to 6 places without scientific nototion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter` to format the labels with the amount of significant digits required. To get e.g. 6 significant digits, use

```
matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.6f}")
```

A full example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(3)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

x = np.linspace(500,900, num=201)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=1e-4,size=len(x) ))+1.0888
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.6f}"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!